# Kafka does not respect topic's retention period on startup?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We're running one ZooKeeper server and one Kafka broker on a test machine. We're using ZooKeeper 3.3.5 and Kafka 0.9.0.1.

The message retention period on the broker is set to 4 hours:

```
log.retention.ms = null
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.hours = 4
log.retention.minutes = null
log.retention.check.interval.ms = 30000
```

We have a single topic whose retention period is essentially infinite (we set it to 50 years).

At some point we shut down then restarted ZooKeeper, then we shut down and restarted the Kafka broker.

Looking at the logs, it seems that the Kafka broker, upon startup, decided to delete old messages, even though they are well within the 50 years retention period.

First, here's Kafka starting up normally:

```
[2016-09-15 09:09:24,877] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-09-15 09:09:24,883] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 10.0.4.83:2182 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,056] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,096] INFO Completed load of log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 with log end offset 102152 (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,105] INFO Logs loading complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,106] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 30000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,107] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,149] INFO Awaiting socket connections on ip-10-0-4-83:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,151] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 1], Started 1 acceptor threads (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,169] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,173] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,244] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,250] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,250] INFO 1 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2016-09-15 09:09:25,321] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
```

Then, 30 seconds later, the log cleanup kicks in and deletes all our messages:

```
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,114] INFO Rolled new log segment for 'ecosystem_sharedmodel-0' in 3 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,115] INFO Scheduling log segment 0 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,115] INFO Scheduling log segment 618 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,115] INFO Scheduling log segment 3052 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,116] INFO Scheduling log segment 6050 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,116] INFO Scheduling log segment 73419 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,116] INFO Scheduling log segment 73553 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,116] INFO Scheduling log segment 82663 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,117] INFO Scheduling log segment 85600 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,117] INFO Scheduling log segment 96316 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,117] INFO Scheduling log segment 99030 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:09:55,117] INFO Scheduling log segment 101756 for log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,116] INFO Deleting segment 618 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,116] INFO Deleting segment 0 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,116] INFO Deleting segment 6050 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,117] INFO Deleting segment 73419 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,117] INFO Deleting segment 3052 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,117] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000073419.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,117] INFO Deleting segment 73553 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,117] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000003052.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,118] INFO Deleting segment 82663 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,118] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000073553.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,118] INFO Deleting segment 85600 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,118] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000082663.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,119] INFO Deleting segment 96316 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,119] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000085600.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,119] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000096316.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,119] INFO Deleting segment 99030 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,119] INFO Deleting segment 101756 from log ecosystem_sharedmodel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,120] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000000000.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,121] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000099030.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,121] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000000618.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,121] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000101756.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
[2016-09-15 09:10:55,123] INFO Deleting index /data/kafka/ecosystem_sharedmodel-0/00000000000000006050.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
```

Is this the expected behavior of Kafka? Is there a misunderstanding on our side? A configuration problem?

EDIT: it turned out to be a user error, no bugs on Kafka's side.

Comment: How are you setting the topic level retention period?

Comment: @NipunTalukdar We're doing `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2182 --alter --topic <topic> --config retention.ms=1576800000000`.

Comment: It turns out this was a user error. No bug on Kafka's side.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune could you comment a bit on the user error? I'm getting a similar situation and I'm completely clueless...

Comment: @ssice One of our SREs mistakenly lowered the retention period on the topic, and Kafka immediately proceeded with deleting messages older than this retention period.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I don't think that was our issue, and still don't know what was the cause.